# Web Page Editor so that Page Refreshes as I Update the JavaScript & HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ide

I am looking for a Html/JavaScript/CSS development tool such that as I type and update any Html/JavaScript/CSS code in the source code, I would be able to see the result in the browser right away without having to refresh.  I've seen some video tutorials where the author is editing the code and the result is automatically shown in a browser window without the author refreshing the page. It should preferably be a free tool.

Thanks

Comment: [Brackets](http://brackets.io) has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe DreamWeaver, but that costs a lot.

Alternatively you may try Google Web Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Coda is a great option, if you are on a Mac